# Installing Ubuntu onto new totally blank laptop drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I am very new to this forgive me if I am asking the silliest question ever!!

I wish to buy a [15.6" UltraNote IV laptop](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/ultraNoteIV-15/) from PC Specialist.

I am opting for:

- i7-7700HQ processor
- the better screen option
- 16GB of Ram
- 1st hard Disk = none
- 2nd Hard disk = none
- M.2SSD drive = Samsung SM961 M.2 PCIe NVMe
- DVD/BluRay drive = 6x ultra slim BluRay Writer
- Bluetooth & Wireless = Gigabit LAN and wireless Intel 8265 vPRO

There will be no operating system installed, because I do not want Windows 10, and PC Specialist will not install Ubuntu. So what will I have to do to get Ubuntu onto the machine and running smoothly without any issues with the wireless / mousepad / keyboard etc?

Thank you!!

Comment: And we don't know if you will have issues with Wi-Fi, etc, because we don't know which wireless adapter is there. If you have any issues you are welcome to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a live DVD or flash drive, and boot into it and install as usual. There really isn't much to do about the drivers if they aren't supported out of the box without manually compiling them.

Comment: As I saidI am new to this.  I can't install "as usual" I have never done this.  If I create an Ubuntu disc would it boot automatically?

Comment: I gave a link with a step by step manual.

Comment: During boot, most computers tell you which key to press to change the boot drive.